# Link in keyup function is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

[Here is screen shot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXMcP.jpg)I am using codeigniter and ajax.When keyup function is call on search bar then data is shown in suggestion box but when i click on link which is shown on suggestion box then this click is not working.No error of any script file.
Here is code of my view file:

```
  <div class="container-fluid my_searchbar">
  <div class="container my_searchbar_container">


    <div class="nav nav-justified navbar-search navbar-nav">                  
    <form class="search navbar-search" method="post" action="index.html" >


    <div class="input-group">            
      <input type="text" name="search_area" id="search_area" placeholder="Search Area" class="form-control input-lg">           
      <div class="input-group-btn">
    </div>
<input type="text" name="search_pro" id="search_pro" placeholder="Search Professional Category" class="form-control input-lg">        
 <ul id="show_search_pro" class="results" >
 </ul>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <a href="../show_professional/showProfessional" class="btn btn-search search_btn btn-lg">Search</a>                    
          </div>
    </div>  


  </form>         
  </div>


  </div>
  </div> 

</div>
```

Here is my ajax code in view file.

```
$('#search_pro').keyup(function(){
// alert($(this).val());

var location_field = $('#search_area');
var search_cal_field = $(this);


$.ajax({

    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/JustClick/User/search_professional',
    cache : false,
    dataType : 'html',
    data :{location_id:location_field.val(), category_id:search_cal_field.val()},

    success:function(data)
    {
        $('#show_search_pro').html(data);
    }
    });
});
```

Here is code of my controller through using ajax i get data on view page:

```
public function search_professional()
    {

        if($this->input->is_ajax_request())
        {
            $professional = $this->UserModel->search_professional($this->input->post('location_id',true),$this->input->post('category_id',true));

            foreach ($professional as $row) 
            {
                echo '

                    <li>
                     <a class="s_pro" href="'.base_url('Professional/show_professional_detail/'.$row->pro_id).'">'.$row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname.'<br /><span>Description...</span></a></li>';


            }
        }
        else
        {
            show_404();
        }

    }
```

Help me how i solve this problem.

Comment: can you add your code to fiddle?

Comment: i dont know about fiddle sir

Comment: I can sent this code on your mail

Comment: Please try to check here what is mistake

Comment: place to upload your code like this https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Sir can you please check problem here?

Comment: So the URL is showing, but if you click on it, it doesn't work? Do you load the url helper in your controller with `$this->load->helper('url');`? Because else the `base_url` function will not work.